# "неповторимо-привлекательность"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, неправильно же говорить "неповторимо-привлекательность" от сокращения слов неповторимость и привлекательность?

Answer (score 2):

Я такого сложного существительного не знаю.

Есть неповторимая привлекательность, неповторимо привлекателен. В любом случае это **некорректное сочетание наречия с существительным.**

Это грамматическая **ошибка словообразования**.

Сложное слово состоит из двух (или более) корней и образуется от самостоятельных частей речи способом сложения:

1) целых слов: диван-кровать

2) основ слов с помощью соединительных гласных о или е: пароход, пешеход

3) основ и суффиксов: полководец

4) начальной части слова с целым словом: пол-арбуза, автовокзал, полутень

5) начальных букв слов или их начальных звуков: ТУ (Тартуский университет), ЭТВ (Эстонское телевидение), ПБК (Первый Балтийский канал)

Ни к одному из этих способов данное слово не относится.